# Generic method - Type cannot be used as Type Parameter

Tags: c#, generics

Given the following Generic Method:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Performs a MoveNext on the IEnumerator 'Enoomerator'. 
    /// If it hits the end of the enumerable list, it resets to the beginning.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>If False, MoveNext has failed even after resetting,
    /// which means there are no entries in the list.</returns>
    private static bool CyclicalSafeMoveNext<T>(T Enoomerator) 
                                           where T : IEnumerator<T> 
    {
        if (Enoomerator.MoveNext()) //  successfully moved to the next element
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            // Either reached last element (so reset to beginning) or
            // trying to enumerate in a list with no entries 
            LogLine("CyclicalSafeMoveNext: failed a MoveNext, resetting.");
            Enoomerator.Reset();

            if (!Enoomerator.MoveNext())
            {
                // Still at end. Zero entries in the list?
                LogLine("CyclicalSafeMoveNext: failed a MoveNext after 
                Reset(), which means there were no entries in the list.");
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                // Resetting was successful
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
```

When I compile this code

```
IEnumerator<FileInfo> FileInfoEnumerator files;                               
while (CyclicalSafeMoveNext(files))
{
    return files.Current.FullName;
}
```

I get the error:

```
Error 7 The type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<System.IO.FileInfo>' cannot 
be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method
'CyclicalSafeMoveNext<T>(T)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from
'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<System.IO.FileInfo>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<System.IO.FileInfo>>'.
```

Why am I getting this error and how do I correct my code?

Comment: I really like your `Enoomerator` :)

Comment: @Noob, yeah, I'm going to get off SO for today.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl, note the hidden characters in the error text, which blockquotes don't show

Comment: You code won't compile for entirely different reasons than the reasons you provided.  You need to provide us with a code sample that can accurately replicate your problem.

Comment: @gunr2171: Wow. Sorry, you're right. I'm pretty sure that on Preview those were visible. Strange. Hm. I've cheked, not, they were not visible. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry about the Error, no matter what I try I can't get the real thing to show up. There's whole clauses that are being dropped.

Comment: @Servy, I copy/pasted then edited for space/brevity.  Not sure what I broke so that it won't compile...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One problem  is here:

```
where T : IEnumerator<T>
```

You're restricting the generic class to a class *that is its own enumerator*.

Since `FileInfo` is not an `IEnumerator<FileInfo>` and `IEnumerator<FileInfo>` is not an `IEnumerator<IEnumerator<FileInfo>>` it fails the generic constraint.

You *could* add a second generic type:

```
private static bool CyclicalSafeMoveNext<T, U>(T Enoomerator) 
                                       where T : IEnumerator<U>
```

or just make `IEnumerator<T>` part of the signature:

```
private static bool CyclicalSafeMoveNext<T>(IEnumerator<T> Enoomerator)
```

Comment: You're right, that's the signature I needed. Clearly I'm not fluent in Generic Method design yet..  and Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

try

```
private static bool CyclicalSafeMoveNext<T>(IEnumerator<T> Enoomerator)
```

having the `where T : IEnumerator<T>` is throwing it off.